# HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure Application Xbap

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, http-error, out-of-process

Recently I have had this problem that comes up often but I don't understand the reason for it.

With **IIS** I have my web site with my api and when I call them I get an answer but I added an application to my web site and this one sends me this error.

My api are in: `C:\inetpub\wwroot\V4_1\`

And the Xbap application can be found in: `C:\Content\AppliWindows\Xbap\`

Some of the servers I use with the same files don't have this problem.

Web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\Spec.Locbus.V4.Services.FrontEnd.exe" arguments="" requestTimeout="00:20:00" stdoutLogEnabled="false" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
      <environmentVariables />
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 821a3cf1-7c3b-4e36-8868-69fd8b417331-->
```

In Windows event log I get this error but it doesn't give me any more information:

> Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/content' with physical root
> 'C:\content' failed to start process with commandline
> '.\Spec.Locbus.V4.Services.FrontEnd.exe ' with multiple retries.
> Failed to bind to port '7993'. First 30KB characters of captured
> stdout and stderr logs from multiple retries:

I know I get the same error when I try to call my api and I didn't install **net.core2.2.8** but I installed it correctly and my api works.

The server I'm on is running **Windows2019**.

Asp.NET diagnostics seems to be good except for 2.2.8 at end of life :

```
System Time: 17/11/2020 15:57:29
Processor Architecture: AMD64
OS: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0

Server Type: IIS
Scan 32 installed module(s).
ASP.NET Core module version 2 is installed for .NET Core 2.2 and above: C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll (13.1.20295.10).

Scan 45 registered handler(s).
Found a valid ASP.NET Core handler as { Name: aspNetCore, Path: *, State: Enabled, Module: AspNetCoreModuleV2, Entry Type: Local }.
Visual C++ runtime is detected (expected: 14.0, detected: 14.28.29325.2 built by: vcwrkspc): C:\Windows\system32\msvcp140.dll.
The application pool 'LocbusV4' is used.
Pool identity is IIS AppPool\LocbusV4
Please ensure pool identity has read access to the content folder C:\inetpub\wwwroot\V4_1.
Pool bitness is 64 bit
Scan aspNetCore section.
    "processPath": .\Spec.Locbus.V4.Services.FrontEnd.exe.
    "arguments": .
    "hostingModel": .
"runtimeTarget": .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2/win-x64.
Runtime is Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/2.2.8.
.NET Core version 2.2.8 is end-of-life. Please upgrade to a supported version.
Runtime 2.2.8 requires ASP.NET Core module version 12.2.19109.5. Installed version 13.1.20295.10 might not be compatible.
Please refer to pages such as https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1 to verify that ASP.NET Core version 13.1.20295.10 matches the runtime of the web app.
```

Has anyone ever had this problem and has a solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Run a report to show more details, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: You can check the log of asp.net core for more information. <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\CoreMVC.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />

Comment: @BruceZhang Hi, I put what you told me in the web.config and when I call an api I get this error: 

***HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure***

Except that when I put the same thing in the web.config of another server that runs it with the same deliverables I get the same error so I don't think it gives me a lead to follow.

Comment: Did you install AspNetCoreModuleV2 correctly in IIS? In asp.net core 2.2 , default Server/ hosting pattern with IIS called IIS InProcess hosting. The web.config points to a new module called AspNetCoreModuleV2 which is required for inprocess hosting. You can get the module from here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-5.0.0-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

Comment: @BruceZhang Yes the module is present in the web.config. I added a screenshot in the post. When at installation I followed your link and install but nothing to change except installing .NetCore5 but I had already downloaded the module by installing Asp.Net core2.2.8.

Comment: Can you double-click to start Spec.Locbus.V4.Services.FrontEnd.exe?If so, please add hostingModel="inprocess" to <aspNetCore processPath=...> and test the application in IIS again.

Comment: @BruceZhang My application is out of process and I already tried this when you first proposed it to me and it didn't work.

Comment: If the application cannot be run out of process or in process,  it is probably an application problem, which requires checking your code. I suggest you create a [support ticket](https://support.microsoft.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I finally succeeded in creating a second site by creating the sub-application in this one and with URL rewriting redirecting the calls intended for the application from site 1 to the site of the app.